# Function almost complete - Need to make it close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

What am I missing?  I am trying to make this function close, I have it working with opening, just can't figure out how to make it close using same code that applies to open...

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.head').click( function(){
       var a = $(this) ;
       var section = $( a.attr('href') );
       section.removeClass('section');
       $('.section').hide();
       section.addClass('section');
       if(! section.is(':visible') ){
              section.fadeIn(400);
        };
    });
});
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.head').click( function(){
       var a = $(this) ;
       var section = $( a.attr('href') );
       section.removeClass('section');
       $('.section').hide();
       section.addClass('section');
       if(! section.is(':visible') ){
              section.fadeIn(400);
        };
       else(! section.is(':visible') ){
              section.fadeOut(400);
       };
    });
});
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "trying to make this function close". Do you want to close over a variable?

Comment: As of right now I have it where on click of a link, the div container called 'Section' will open up to the right (fadeIn).  I'd like it where, if I click on the same link, that div container 'Section' will close

Comment: `toggleClass`? http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Couldn't you just use `fadeOut` to close it?

Comment: @Asad Yes, but where would I include that?

Comment: When you check for the element being hidden and show it, add an else clause to hide it.

Comment: so near the bottom, add:  if(! section.is(':visible') ){ section.fadeIn(400); else(! section.is(':visible') ){section.fadeOut(400);};}; ...I'm so confused...

Comment: @Hybrid82 That isn't the correct syntax for an if/else clause. Please take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

Comment: I made an edit to my original post, could you look it over and let me know where I'm going wrong - What I have doesn't work...

Comment: @sushain97, would I need to edit the section.removeClass('section'); and make it section.toggleClass('section'); to make this work?

Comment: `else(! section.is(':visible') ){` should just be `else`.

Comment: @Hybrid82 Again, the syntax you're using for the if/else clause is incorrect. There's no semicolon separating the if and else blocks, and the else clause doesn't need a condition in front of it, since it is entered whenever the condition in front of `if` isn't true. In the lines above, you're adding and immediately removing a class from an element for seemingly no reason. Getting `var section = $( a.attr('href') );` doesn't make any sense, since the `href` attribute of a link isn't a selector. I think you need to slow down and go through some tutorials until you're more comfortable with this.

Comment: @Jonathan, so it would just be else(){}; ???

Comment: Nope, `else` does not check a condition so just `else {..}`.

Comment: @Hybrid82 There would be no parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
if( section.is(':visible') ){
  section.hide()
}
else{
  section.fadeIn(400);
};
```

Comment: What about all the stuff above?

Comment: PERFECT!  Michael B. you did it again mate !  Thank you ever soo much!